# Looking for a nicer way to select from multiple lists based on type

Tags: c#, generics, switch-statement

I have the following code which returns a list for a specific entity type when called. I am looking for a more elegant way to do this, as now I have to create an instance of the generic to feed into switch and I do not like that, but the rest is very concise and readable. I saw a [different notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61746384/7091281) but I think it is worse than what I have already.

```
switch (typeof(T))
{
    case Type intType when intType == typeof(int):
        ...
    case Type decimalType when decimalType == typeof(decimal):
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

My current code:

```
public List<Guid> GetListForType<T>() where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    //HACK: Cannot find a nicer way to do this
    return new T() switch
    {
        Education => EducationSelection,
        Language => LanguageSelection,
        Knowledge => KnowledgeSelection,
        Work => WorkSelection,
        Project => ProjectSelection,
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
}

#region Lists

public List<Guid> EducationSelection { get; set; } = new();
//Note: Languages not currently in use
public List<Guid> LanguageSelection { get; set; } = new();
public List<Guid> KnowledgeSelection { get; set; } = new();
public List<Guid> WorkSelection { get; set; } = new();
public List<Guid> ProjectSelection { get; set; } = new();

#endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all the lists into a `Dictionary<Type, List<Guid>>`

```cs
public List<Guid> GetListForType<T>() where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    return _lists.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var list)
           ? list
           : throw new NotImplementedException();
}

#region Lists

private Dictionary<Type, List<Guid>> _lists = new Dictionary<Type, List<Guid>>
{
  { typeof(Education), new List<Guid>() },
  { typeof(Language),  new List<Guid>() },
  { typeof(Knowledge), new List<Guid>() },
  { typeof(Work),      new List<Guid>() },
  { typeof(Project),   new List<Guid>() },
};

#endregion
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not want a new list for every call, I want to specifically return a list from the object that is used to store IDs for the specified generic type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The lists are all cached in a field. They are no regenerated on every call.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that. Yeah that would probably work though it is a database entity so I would need to link the specific lists instead of creating new ones.

Comment: So you would do `{ typeof(Education), DbContext.Educations },` or something like that and declare it as `Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Guid>>`

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you can try to implement **Abstract Factory Method**. You can create an interface or abstract class, all these Selection props can inherit from this base class.

Also, you can check this StackOverFlow question.

[Factory Pattern without a Switch or If/Then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878216/factory-pattern-without-a-switch-or-if-then)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an option?

```
public List<Guid> GetListForType<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    
    if (type == typeof(Education)) return EducationSelection;
    if (type == typeof(Language)) return LanguageSelection;
    
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It's not minimalistic, but you do get rid of the `new()`-ing.

Comment: I did think about that one and I will switch to it in case new() ever becomes an issue.